# CakePHP - Exclude Models from JOIN in find() method

Tags: php, cakephp, join, recursion, find

I'm currently working on a project with CakePHP and its find() method to handle database queries.

My current situation is as follows:

I have 3 Models: `User`, `Location` and `Order`. The connection is that a `User hasOne Location` and `User hasMany Orders`.

When I'm using the find() method to get the User and the address (stored in the Location model) CakePHP returns the User, Location, and the Order Models. In my case, I don't need the Order information.

So my question is: Is it possible to tell CakePHP not to join with the Order Model?

I know about the `recursive` attribute, but if I set it to `-1`, CakePHP returns just the User Model and in the case of recursive >= 0, it returns all 3 Models.

Answer (score 2):

Solved problem with Containable of cakephp. The code is as follows:

```
$this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');

$this->User->recursive = -1;
$this->paginate = array('fields' => array('User.*'),
                        'contain' => array('Location'=>array('field1', 'field2')
                       );

$user = $this->Paginator->paginate('User');
```

Comment: The original version of that code should be in the question. Bravo for solving and answering your own question, +1. (Please fix your whitespace, it was easier to read before your last edit).

Answer (score 1):

You can use unbind model function to exclude desired models

In your case :

```
$this->User->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => 'Orders'));
```

For common

```
$this->User->unbindModel(
            array(
                'hasMany' => array('Model1','Model2'),
                'hasOne' => array('Model1','Model2'),
                'belongsTo' => array('Model1','Model2'),
                )
        );
```